# Node : Data sent acknowledgement to TCP server

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I have implemented TCP server and client as Angular/Hercules is there is any way in node js that when server sends some data to client then server has assurance that data is successfully reached to client. in node we have `client.write('hello from server');` to send data, can i use callback here also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what you will need is to open a duplex socket and just notify from the client that you received the message.

But TCP usually by protocol signifies that your data will be acknowledged so you will not need to actually check it. That can make sense for UDP protocol thought.